# How can I partition this table?

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I want to track the states of subscriptions between a contact and a list. The states are...

- pending
- subscribed

  - resubscribed (a subset of subscribed)
- unsubscribed

I also want to know when each step happened. Rather than using a single field I'm using three timestamps.

- created_at
- subscribed_at
- unsubscribed_at

The states correspond to:

- pending: `subscribed_at is null`
- subscribed: `subscribed_at > coalesce(unsubscribed_at, '-infinity')`

  - resubscribed: `... and unsubscribed_at is not null`
- unsubscribed: `coalesce(unsubscribed_at, '-infinity') > subscribed_at`

The major operations are...

- Find pending subscriptions for a contact and list.
- Find active subscriptions for a contact, a list, or both.
- Find unsubscriptions for a contact, a list, or both.
- Delete old pending subscriptions.
- Delete old unsubscriptions.

This table can potentially get quite large. We have in the order of 10,000,000 contacts and 100 lists. A contact has about 10 active subscriptions. A list can have in the order of 100,000 active subscriptions. Old pending and unsubscriptions will be purged periodically.

I'm anticipating most queries will use subscribed_at and unsubscribed_at which will complicate indexing. I'd like to partition the table into pending, subscribed, and unsubscribed, but I can't figure out how.

This is using PostgreSQL 12.

Comment: How can you tell the age of a pending subscription?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe There are also created_at and updated_at timestamps.

Comment: Then you need to partition by one of those. Partition so that removing data becomes `DROP TABLE`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't see how partitioning by any one timestamp helps with the queries. Partitioning by range(created_at) also needs where subscribed_at is null to capture just pending rows. Maybe sub-partitioning? First `partition by list(subscribed_at)` with a default partition and a "pending" partition `for values in (null)` which can be further `partitioned by range(created_at)`. The default partition would need to be sub-partitioned by whether `subscribed_at > coalesce(unsubscribed_at, '-infinity')` is true or false, is that possible?

Comment: Partitioning makes most queries slower. You can either partition for speed (if you have certain clearly defined analytical queries) or for discarding data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Hmm. Any suggestions on how to better solve the problem? I was toying with table inheritance. Maybe the indexing problem isn't as bad as I imagine.

Comment: That depends on your queries and how exactly you want to purge old data. I can answer a single question, but this is not the forum for consultation. Sorry.